# Usar variable de otra clase asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, vb

Estoy con asp.net y tengo en site master dos variables publicas las cuales relleno a través de un dataset.

```
usuario = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Nombre").ToString
grupo = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Grupo").ToString
```

Quiero utilizar estas variables en otra clase pero no lo consigo, como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: En otra clase cualquiera ? o en una `Page` ??

Comment: lo necesito en ambas diria, la variable la tengo en Site.Master.vb y la necesito utilizar en Edicion.aspx.vb, y aparte tambien la otra variable la necesito utilizar para incluir su valor en un textbox

Comment: Guarda el usuario y el grupo en variables sesión. ejemplo:    Session("usuario") = "user1"  Session("grupo") = "NombreGrupo". Luego puedes consultar las variables sessión desde otras clases

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener una variable o propiedad publica de la clase `SiteMaster` en cualquier `Page`, puedes hacer simplemente

```csharp
SiteMaster master = Master as SiteMaster;
var usuario = master.usuario;
```

Esto hacerlo en una clase cualquier es más complicado, no recuerdo si existe forma directa de hacerlo (está tecnología no la veo hace tiempo)

Un forma, quizás no tan buena es que coloques esas variables como estáticas, así las puedes llamar desde cualquier lado.

```
SiteMaster.usuaio
```

Otra forma seria guardándolo en una de las tantas colecciones que existen dentro del `context`, como por ejemplo `Items`

En tu master page guardas la información

```
public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //código anterior
        Context.Items.Add("usuario", usuario);
    }
}
```

Y en cualquier clase podrías leerla como:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
var a = context.Items["usuario"] as EltipoDeUsuario;
```

Pero tienes que tener mucho cuidado con el [ciclo de vida](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)) de la página, porque según donde llames a las variables del MasterPage puede (o no) que aun no se haya llegado al punto en que son seteadas en el MasterPage. Esto es cierto para ambos métodos que te he presentado. Dicho de otro modo el `Page_Load` de una pagina se ejecuta antes del evento `Page_Load` del MasterPage

Tenemos esta clase

```
public class Class1
{
    Public UnaClaseUsuario usuario {get;set;}
    public Class1()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        usuario = context.Items["usuario"] as UnaClaseUsuario ;
    }
}
```

Y en un Page cualquiera:
**Esto no funciona**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        var usuario = class1.usuario;// Esto es nulo, porque lo llamamos demasiado pronto, aun no ha pasado por el masterpage 
    }
}
```

Esto si funciona

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    //notar que cambiamos "Page_Load" por "Page_LoadComplete"
    protected void Page_LoadComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Class1 class1 = new Class1();
        var usuario = class1.usuario;
    }
}
```

En VB, sería algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Algo no hago bien, mi codigo es en vb. He probado cambiandolo pero nada, ninguna de la formas consigo que me funcione. No se si es porque la utilizo en un evento al hacer click.

En el primer caso el codigo que he usado es este:

```
Dim stm As SiteMaster = TryCast(stm, SiteMaster)
Dim usuario = stm.usuario

```
Y este el error que me aparece:

System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

stm fue Nothing.

Comment: Mi idea es:

Tengo un SiteMaster, que al abrir la web ejecuta una consulta a la base de datos el usuario y el grupo, esto lo he guardado en una variable.

En otra clase y documento distinto quiero utilizar esa variable. Es un creador de articulo con simplemente nombre y codigo. Quiero tanto denegar el click al boton en caso de que el grupo sea diferente de 0 como para guardar el usuario que crea el articulo

Comment: En VB es `Dim master As SiteMaster = TryCast(Page.Master, SiteMaster)`

Comment: Me faltaba el Page delante de Master...No me coge el valor, si depuro en SiteMaster si que lo coge pero luego he creado una label para probar que coge el campo pero nada. AL depurar me aparece como Nothing. Este es el codigo: `Dim master As SiteMaster = TryCast(Page.Master, SiteMaster)
        Dim usuario = master.usuario
        ctl02.Text = usuario `

Comment: Y eso donde lo pusiste ??? (en que evento)

Comment: Tengo esto en la parte de Articulo.apsx:
**<asp:Button ID="btnValidar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-block"  Text="VALIDAR" OnClick="btnValidar_Click" />**

Y luego en Receta.aspx.vb tengo:  `Public Sub btnValidar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim master As SiteMaster = TryCast(Page.Master, SiteMaster)
        Dim usuario = master.usuario
        ctl02.Text = usuario
    End Sub `
`

Comment: Algo como esto:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcVOY.png

Comment: Lo tengo igual, he probado dandole un valor a usuario y si funciona. Creo que el problema viene a la hora de asignar el valor a usuario, seguramente en el dataset: (https://imgur.com/ZycTQKI)

Comment: Tu problema es `If Not IsPostBack Then`, el código se ejecuta cuando NO es un postback y el presionar un botton ES un postback